# Custom Directive for not Create Component

Tags: vue.js

I have a custom directive for checking user roles for some component will be shown or not.

```
Vue.directive("permission", {
bind(el, binding) {
  Vue.nextTick(() => {
     el.vFillMarkerNode = document.createComment('');
     el.parentNode.insertBefore(el.vFillMarkerNode, el.nextSibling);
     if (Auth.canSee(binding.value)) {
      el.textContent = binding.value;
    } else {
      el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    }
  });
},
```

This will work but in the component which is not shown, It will get the data from api (on component created hook) even user does not have permission.

```
<mycomp v-permission="['Admin']"></mycomp>
```

Is there any way to tell the vue, if my directive condition does not fit, do not fire related component 'created' hook, so do not get data from api?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the right way to do what you are trying to do. Since you are depending on the root-element on the component in order to do your checks. You are doing your checks after the component has already mounted. hence the `Vue.nexTick()`.

There are a two ways you could solve this issue.

1. Run your logic in the `Vuex Store` and use `mapGetters` in the parent component to get the permissions in all of your components.
2. Bind your permissions to the root element and do `v-if="$root.permissions.includes('admin')"` on your component